# How to grep by section?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, sed, grep

I have a file structured like that:

```
BOF

-------Title1-------
stuff here
some stuff

-------Title2-------
extra things
extra things
extra things

-------Title3-------
and some stuff
   here

...

-------Title4-------
stuff

EOF
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
grep-by-section KEYWORD DELIMITER my-file
```

so that

```
grep-by-section "some" "^---" my-file
```

outputs

```
-------Title1-------
stuff here
some stuff

-------Title3-------
and some stuff
   here
```

I want to find a certain keyword and for every finding I want to output the whole block between known delimiters. How can I do that? `sed` fails me here.

Delimiters here are "------", but could be something else like numbers in [0-9]{8} format for example.

A similar problem which I couldn't solve is instead of outputting the contents of the block, output just the title of the block.

It seems to be easier to solve with `perl` than `sed`

Comment: I think `awk` would be a good solution.  See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628017/) for a similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($search, $del) = splice(@ARGV, 0, 2);
local $/;
while (<>) {
   for (/($del(?:(?!$del).)*)/smg) {
      print if /$search/sm;
   }
}
```

Notes:

- `local $/` causes the following readline to read a file at a time instead of a line at a time.
- `(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

Comment: Wow.  That is awesome, but can you make it more readable for us mortals?  ;)  (Hi ikegami!)

Answer (score 1):

[agrep](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/) can do this via: `agrep -d DELIMITER KEYWORD FILE`

Answer (score 0):

If there are true empty lines between those records, you would not need to use those delimiters, this would suffice:

```
awk '/KEYWORD/' RS= ORS='\n\n' file
```

Otherwise you could also try this awk:

```
awk '
  $0~key{
    f=1
  }
  $0~del{
    if(f)print s
    f=0
    s=$0
    next
  }
  {
    s=s RS $0
  }
  END{
    if(f)print s
  }
' key="KEYWORD" del="DELIMITER" file
```

In one line:

```
awk '$0~key{f=1} $0~del{ if(f)print s ; f=0; s=$0; next } {s=s RS $0} END{ if(f)print s }' key="KEYWORD" del="DELIMITER" file
```