# Using PowerShell in a .bat file, replace a string with multiple strings

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace, windows-10

I'm using a .baat to move several files into another folder, but before the actual move part, I want to replace the LAST line (it is a known line), for example I have a file output.txt like this:

```
HEADER
    BODY
 FOOTER
```

Using this snippet of code:

```
powershell -Command "(gc output.txt) -replace 'FOOTER', 'ONE_MORE_LINE `r`n FOOTER' | Out-File output.txt"
```

The return that I expected was

```
HEADER
    BODY
 ONE_MORE_LINE
 FOOTER
```

But what I got was:

```
HEADER
    BODY
 ONE_MORE_LINE `r`n FOOTER
```

I've tried:

- `\n`
- `<br>`
- `` "`r`n" ``
- `` "`n" ``
- `echo ONE_MORE_LINE >> output.txt; echo. >> output.txt; echo  FOOTER >> output.txt"`

This last one got close, but the result was some broken characters.

Other suggestions besides the PowerShell are welcome. I'm only using it because it was an easy get way to do the adding lines and replace it.

EDIT :
Tried this command

```
powershell -Command "(gc output.txt) -replace 'FOOTER;', ""ONE_MORE_LINE `r`n FOOTER"" | Out-File output.txt "
```

And returned this error:

```
A cadeia de caracteres não tem o terminador: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

EDIT2 - Possible Solution:

I realized that using the PowerShell command altered the encoding of the file, breaking the `echo ONE_MORE_LINE`, and using the suggestion from @AnsgarWiechers, I made this code

```
findstr /v "FOOTER" output.sql > new_output.sql
TYPE new_output.sql > output.sql
del new_output.sql
ECHO. >> %%f
ECHO ONE_MORE_LINE >> %%f
ECHO FOOTER >> %%f
ECHO. >> %%f
```

What it does is using the commant `findstr /v` "FOOTER" I look for all lines that are not FOOTER in the file output.sql and Write it on new_output.sql

Then I `TYPE` it back to the original file, and `DEL` the new_output.sql

Then I `Echo` all the lines I need right under it.

It works BUT, for big files I think that re-writing it twice will take a lot of time, but I can't figure an other solution.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't expand escape sequences in single-quoted strings. You must use a double-quoted string there. Double the nested double quotes to escape them for CMD: ``powershell -Command "(...) -replace 'FOOTER', ""ONE_MORE_LINE `r`n FOOTER"" | ..."``

Comment: You could do this in pure batch with a `FOR /F` command.  You just hold the previous line in a variable. When the next line is read write out the previous line.  When the `FOR` command is done write out your second to last line and then your last line which will be held in the previous variable.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - When I doubled the nested double quotes it returned an error, saying that the chain of characters does not have an end.

Comment: @Squashman Could you show me how to re-write it using pure batch ?

Comment: Please update your question with the modified command and the exact error message.

Comment: Try escaping the nested double quotes with backslashes: ``powershell -Command "(...) -replace 'FOOTER', \"ONE_MORE_LINE `r`n FOOTER\" | ..."``.

Answer (score 0):

When working with big files it's best to use a file stream.  More typical methods of reading a file line-by-line using a Batch `for /f` loop or using `Get-Content` in PowerShell to read the entire file into memory can slow the process to a crawl with large files.  Using a file stream on the other hand, you can nearly instantly seek back from the end of the file to the beginning of the last line, insert your desired data, and then reassemble the bytes you overwrote.

The following example will use PowerShell's access to .NET methods to open a file as a byte stream for rapid reading and writing.  See inline comments for details.  File encoding will hopefully be preserved.  Save this with a **.bat** extension and give it a shot.

```perl
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "file=test.txt"
set "line=Line to insert!"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid #>

# construct a file stream for reading and writing $env:file
$IOstream = new-object IO.FileStream((gi $env:file).FullName,
    [IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate, [IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite)

# read BOM to determine file encoding
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader($IOstream)
[void]$reader.Read((new-object byte[] 3), 0, 3)
$encoding = $reader.CurrentEncoding
$reader.DiscardBufferedData()

# convert line-to-insert to file's native encoding
$utf8line = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`r`n$env:line")
$line = [Text.Encoding]::Convert([Text.Encoding]::UTF8, $encoding, $utf8line)
$charSize = [math]::ceiling($line.length / $utf8line.length)

# move pointer to the end of the stream
$pos = $IOstream.Seek(0, [IO.SeekOrigin]::End)

# walk back pointer while stream returns no error
while ($char -gt -1) {
    $IOstream.Position = --$pos
    $char = $reader.Peek()
    $reader.DiscardBufferedData()

    # break out of loop when line feed preceding non-whitespace is found
    if ($foundPrintable) { if ($char -eq 10) { break } }
    else { if ([char]$char -match "\S") { $foundPrintable++ } }
}

# step pointer back to carriage return and read to end into $buffer with $line prepended
$pos -= $charSize
$IOstream.Position = $pos
$buffer = $encoding.GetBytes($encoding.GetString($line) + $reader.ReadToEnd())
$IOStream.Position = $pos

"Inserting data at byte $pos"
$IOstream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)

# Garbage collection
$reader.Dispose()
$IOstream.Dispose()
```

This method should be much more efficient than reading the file from the beginning, or copying the entire file into memory or on disk with a new line inserted.  In my testing, it inserts the line into a hundred meg file in about 1/3 of a second.

Comment: Note that "large files" in this case requires several GiB to be annoyingly slow. And even then, if you just do basic replacements you can use `-ReadCount` for `Get-Content` to speed it up quite a bit. I doubt they actually have that large files that this kind of complexity is needed, though.

Comment: @Joey In my experience, even parsing 100 meg file can take upwards of an hour or more.  [See this thread of comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628017/regexp-match-within-a-log-file-return-dynamic-content-above-and-below-match#comment22178573_15629509) for one such example why I'm once bitten, twice shy, why I default to recommending a stream parser for this sort of task.  I would be interested in seeing how you can implement `gc -ReadCount` to speed up the task, if you feel up to posting an answer.

Comment: I recently had to write a script that took a 10 GiB CSV file and replace strings in it. It took minutes (annoyingly), but definitely not hours. `-ReadCount` would greatly cut down on pipeline overhead, but may complicate code after `Get-Content` in the pipeline. It's a trade-off. I may do some tests once I'm no longer at work.